# Postfix — Old queued messages won't send out through new SMTP server

Tags: email, postfix

I updated our Postfix SMTP server (using a relay server) as the relay server was blocking us. New emails are going out without any problem but the older ones that were in queue are not. I tried to requeue the messages and then flushed them but I am still getting an error "mail transport unavailable". I assume the messages are still trying to use the old SMTP server. Can anyone help me out on how to resolve this issue?

If it helps these messages are saying

relay=none, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)

From the research I have been looking into I see that I need to use postsuper to put the message on hold first and then postcat to save it to an .eml file. The messages have attachments so not sure if it's possible to grab that using postcat. Any help would be appreciated.

This is on running on CentOS 6 so I don't have the option of -bh.

Thanks

Comment: Try flushing emails `postfix -f`

Comment: Are you getting any error while running `postconf -n`

Comment: I tried the postconf -f and the reloading, that didn't work. I also don't see any errors with postconf -n, just configuration information.

Comment: Can you please update your main.cf file with transport file details.

Comment: I also have this issue. Fixed a configuration and the mail in the queue is stuck.